# How is the Book of Life / Death organized?

Tags: theology, rosh-hashanah-new-year

Are these just two books containing lists of people detined to die and one destined for life? Or does each person have his own life and death book?

How does it work from one year to the next? If it's on ebook, does your name go from the death book to the life book? Is a new book created each year? Or is last year's book re-opened and a new entry made? Are old entries deleted?

Comment: https://64.media.tumblr.com/57e0fa1cc6305e4205c05330df31d6df/tumblr_nhztk6EDlc1r426i4o1_500.gif

Comment: Was the סֵּ֣פֶר חַיִּ֑ים Sefer Chayim made before Adam, or created after Adam?

Comment: A perfect way to ruin a nice metaphor is to start thinking about it. +1

Comment: I came here to make the same kind of comment as @AlBerko, but he got here first. I mean, books are physical objects; there wouldn't be literal books or scrolls in Shamayim.